# While loops. How to loop Strings

Tags: c#, loops, console, console-application

I am Working on this very simple Quiz, and what I am trying to do is to run the code and answer the question and have an infinite loop which ends in the correct answer.
This is the closest I have come to completing it and I need some help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Media;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What Countries Capital City is Oslo, Choose From the Following: ");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("1.Norway, 2.Sweden, 3.Germany");
            String Answer = Console.ReadLine();

            while (Answer != null)
            {
                if (Answer == "Norway")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("That is Correct!");
                    Console.Read();
                }
                else if (Answer != "Norway")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("That is Incorrect!");
                    Console.Read();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I have used a while loop but the while loop does not loop if the answer is false, it only loops once, but I need it to infinitely loop until the answer is correct.

Comment: **[How to use the AWESOME Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: you have three problems you should try and solve,  one is the condition for your loop, you don't keep getting new answers from the user, and you imply to the user to enter a number not the full country name

Comment: For consoles input loops, I would always advise for the do...while loop. It will run at least once, but can be forced to repeat until the proper answer (or a cancel input) is given. Menus. Using inputting a valid number. All those things I do with do...while.

Comment: Also, I have no idea why you are sleeping for 5 seconds before showing the user their options..

Comment: How does your user know to type in the city name? Your prompt ("1.Norway") implies they should type in `1<ENTER>` which won't match.

Comment: Thank you Ever so much Everyone, Amazing Feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to alter your `while` predicate:

```
while (Answer != "Norway")
```

You will also need to set your answer variable inside the loop:

```
String Answer = String.Empty;

while (Answer != Norway)
{
    Answer = Console.ReadLine();
    if (Answer == "Norway")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That is Correct!");
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That is Incorrect!");
    }
}
```

I have removed the Console.Read() statements as they aren't necessary.

You may wish to print the question again each time the user enters the wrong input.

You could also make the answer case-insensitive, by changing the predicate thus:

```
while (!Answer.Equals("Norway", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: Amazing Thank you very much Igby. I Wasnt aware i could manipulate the String Answer as you did Thank you

Comment: @Jerry0 You're welcome! Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code with debugger.

you need to find what is different between "Console.ReadLine()" and "Console.Read()".
--> Actually I've learn from your mistake.

Please don't forget, in while loop, "String Answer" should be re-assigned value by input of user.